# Can I get plain value of columns with DbDataReader

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I need to get the value in numeric columns from the DB exactly it is formatted. When I get it with the DBDataReader for the numeric columns it automatically converts them to Int32 or Decimal and I get unwanted zeroes after the decimal point.

So is there a way I can get just the plain value (string) from a column like this? Due to nature of the page I don't want to format them in the code I just want the plain value from the DB.

I tried to get it with GetValue method of DBDataReader but the method is working only for nvarchar columns.

Update from comments:

*I am dealing with unknown columns and types (user select SQL View out of many) and I dynamically create everything. But I don't know the types of the columns nor their preferred formatting. So this is the reason I want the value as it is recorded in the DB. Do you think I can get it as a string?*

Comment: The application reading a `int` as a `int32` is to be expected; those are the correct mappings. Controlling the format of what a value looks like is meant to be done in the presentation layer; that's exactly what it's purpose it.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the quick response! I am aware that this is part of the presentation layer but this case is more strange than normal. I am dealing with unknown columns and types (user select SQL View out of many) and I dynamically create everything. But I don't know the types of the columns nor their preferred formatting. So this is the reason I want the value as it is recorded in the DB. Do you think I can get it as a string?

Answer (score 1):

Like Larnu said in the comments this is accurate mappings for numeric columns for int32 and int. That being said depending on what youre actually trying to do with this data, you could try either using this:

```
reader[index].ToString();
```

or you could try doing

```
reader.GetInt32(index)
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem is I want to get the value exactly it is recorded in the db. Not as int or decimal. On this page I am dealing with user selected SQL Views and I can't format the column properly on the presentation layer. I just don't know the types of the columns nor their preferred format. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: @AlexanderPetkov Can you provide more detail on the data? Like some sort of example so we can get a better understanding?

Comment: Here are some examples:
I got one SQL View that is returning table with columns Price, Year, ExchangeRate, GBPTotal and I need to format the Price and GBPTotal to 2 decimal places and ExchangeRate to 4 decimal places. In the db they are already formatted properly. The task will be easy if this is the only thing I should do but on the page I am working on you can select from 300+ SQL Views all with different columns so I can't map for every SQL View different formatting rules. I just want the plain value from the DB. 
Do you think it's possible?